# Using JSON-LD language maps for CSVW metadata properties

Tags: json, csv, rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

The JSON-LD spec [supports at least two ways](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#string-internationalization) to specify a multilingual property, [language maps](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#language-maps):

```
{
  "greeting": {
    "en": "hello world",
    "fr": "bonjour monde"
  }
}
```

and arrays of [value objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#dfn-value-object):

```
{
  "greeting": [
    {"@language": "en", "@value": "hello world"}
    {"@language": "fr", "@value": "bonjour monde"}
  ]
}
```

The tabular data (CSV on the Web) spec draft [mandates language maps](https://w3c.github.io/csvw/metadata/#dfn-natural-language-property) for spec-defined properties like `titles`, but the primer [uses value objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-primer/#multilingual-metadata) for extra metadata like `dc:title`.

Can I use language maps for things like `dc:title` as well, and if so, how does [normalization](https://w3c.github.io/csvw/metadata/#normalization) interact with that?